# Bootstrap Modal can't be scrolled

Tags: css, modal-dialog, overflow, bootstrap-modal

Bootstrap Modal can't scroll with mouse. Instead, whole website in background is scrolling. Here's my code:

```
.modal-open {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.modal-open .modal {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

Here is URL: http://veritaswp.excellence.lt/dirbtinis-akmuo/dekton/ (you can click on "Spalvų variantai" to see this modal.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can fix it by adding overflow: scroll and max-height in your .modal-content class.

```
.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 0;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  outline: 0;
  max-height: 500px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't help. Give a notice to the fact, that with keyboards UP / DOWN modal scrolls. Just doesn't work with mouse scrolling.